# Execute Stored Procedure in Multiple Task Sets

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library

I have a stored procedure that returns about 10K records, but it takes too much time due to record comparison and other SQL operations.

So I decided to get the results in multiple small sets like:

- 1-1000
- 1001 - 2000

I have created a small program in C# using `Task` operations. However, there is no significant effect on performance.

```
var dataCount = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(strConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_DataCount", SqlParameter);

var totalCount = Convert.ToDouble(dataCount);
var itemsForThread = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / 10);
var pages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / itemsForThread);

var tasks = new List<Task>();

var resultDs = new List<DataSet>();

for (int page = 0; page < pages; page++)
{
    var rangeFrom = (page * itemsForThread) + 1;
    var rangeTo = (page + 1) * itemsForThread;

    var sps = new SqlParameter[2];

    sps[1] = new SqlParameter("@rangeFrom", rangeFrom);
    sps[2] = new SqlParameter("@rangeTo", rangeTo);

    DataSet subDataset = new DataSet();
    resultDs.Add(subDataset);

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => downloadDataThread(subDataset, sps, page));

    tasks.Add(task);

    Task.Delay(500).Wait();
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The function calling the stored procedure creates a new connection for each task:

```
private void downloadDataThread(DataSet ds, SqlParameter[] objsp, int thread)
{
    string[] tablename = { "tbldata" };

    // always creates a new connection
    SqlHelper.FillDataset(strConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_GetData", ds, tablename, objsp);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you first investigate why "it takes too much time due to record comparison and other SQL operations". Upload your execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes, the store procedure is slow due to bad indexing and table structure. It was created 8 years ago. currently, I can't change it due dependencies on the other apps. I am trying to make it possible quicker on the C# level.